# 1/1 bug for DateEdit when property DateYear is "Year not shown"

Tags: forms, date, axapta

When I add a "DateEdit" control to a form and set the DateYear property to "Year not shown" I get the desired behavior. A date is shown without the year (ex.: "23/3" for 23th of March). However, when the users enters 1/1 this value disappears immediately.

Is this an AX bug? Any advice on how to solve this issue? Which method can I override?

Answer (score 1):

The date field is still a date, even when the year is not shown.

When the user enters 1/1 it may be interpreted as 01-01-1900, which happens to be the "null" value of a date.

I see no easy workaround other than use a day and month field instead.